# Sufficient condition for equality of two radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ X $ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $ \phi_1 $ and $  \phi_2 $ be two Radon measures on X (outer measure means measure and the definition of Radon measure that I am assuming can be found on Federer's book or Gariepy Evans book). Suppose that for every $ f \in K(X) $ (the space of all continuous functions with compact support) it holds

$ \int f d\phi_1 = \int f d\phi_2 $

Then I want to prove that $ \phi_1 = \phi_2 $.

What I can prove is that if $ W $ is an open subset such that $ \phi_1(W),\phi_2(W)< \infty $ then $ \phi_1(W)=\phi_2(W) $. This implies:

1) If X has a countable basis then the statement is true.

2) If X is compact then the statement is true.

Now I do not know if the general case is true....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use the definition of Radon measure as in Federer's book, *Geometric Measure Theory* (2.2.5) as follows:

> By a **Radon measure** we mean a measure $\phi$, over a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, with the following three properties:
>
> 1. If $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, then $\phi(K)<\infty$.
> 2. If $V$ is an open subset of $X$, then $V$ is $\phi$-measurable and
>      $$\phi(V)=\sup\left\{\phi(K):K\text{ is compact, }K\subseteq V\right\}.$$
> 3. If $A$ is any subset of $X$, then 
>      $$\phi(A)=\inf\left\{\phi(V):V\text{ is open, }A\subseteq V\right\}.$$

Now, let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as in your question. To show that $\phi_1=\phi_2$, it is sufficient, by property 3, to show that $\phi_1(V)=\phi_2(V)$ for $V$ open. By property 2, it suffices to show that $\phi_1(K)=\phi_2(K)$ for $K$ compact.

Let $K\subseteq X$ compact. By 1, $\phi_1(K)$ and $\phi_2(K)<\infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. By 3 (and taking intersections, if necessary), we can find some open set $V$ such that $K\subseteq V$ and $\phi_i(V)<\phi_i(K)+\varepsilon$ ($i=1,2$). Also, by local compactness, we can shrink $V$ a little and assume that $\overline{V}$ is compact.

By Urysohn's Lemma, choose $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(K)=1$, $f(X\setminus V)=0$. Then $\text{supp}f\subseteq\overline{V}$, so $f\in K(X)$. For a subset $A\subseteq X$, write $1_A:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for the function that is $1$ in $A$ and $0$ in $X\setminus A$. Then
$$\phi_1(K)=\int 1_Kd\phi_1\leq\int fd\phi_1=\int fd\phi_2\leq\int 1_Vd\phi_2=\phi_2(V)<\phi_2(K)+\varepsilon.$$

Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$, we obtain $\phi_1(K)\leq\phi_2(K)$. Changing roles of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, we conclude that $\phi_1(K)=\phi_2(K)$ for every compact $K$, hence $\phi_1=\phi_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is exactly what I proved but of course I missed the point that for property 2) it is sufficient to show the property for opejn sets with compact closure!